# How to add a certificate to a sub-sub-domain with Cloudflare?

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

I'm wondering how I could add a SSL Certificate to a sub-sub-domain on Cloudflare like for example `maintenance.login.example.com` I've already added the sub-sub-domain to my site but I keep getting this error `This site can’t provide a secure connection maintenance.login.example.com sent an invalid response. Try running Windows Network Diagnostics. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Comment: You have it set to the orange cloud and not the grey one, correct? And have you tried on a separate device with a separate network connection (I like to test on a phone using cellular data)?

Comment: @ManmeetGill I have done that, and yes done that too

Answer (score 1):

Our default/free certificates—"Universal SSL"—cover the apex of your domain (example.com) and one level of wildcard (*.example.com).

If you'd like to cover additional levels beyond that, e.g., *.test.example.com or maintenance.login.example.com, you can either purchase a Dedicated Certificate with Custom Hostnames or you can upload a custom certificate to a Business plan or higher.

I wrote a blog post describing Dedicated Certificates here: https://blog.cloudflare.com/dedicated-ssl-certificates.